# Handle KeyPressEvent of QgsMapCanvas

Tags: python-3.x, qgis

I am trying to add some logic at keyPressEvent of a QgsMapCanvas. I have tried handling all the events but none of them are being caught.
Here is what I have tried so far:

```
    QgsMapCanvas.eventFilter = self.keyPressEvent
    QgsMapCanvas.event = self.keyPressEvent
    QgsMapCanvas.enterEvent = self.keyPressEvent
    QgsMapCanvas.keyReleaseEvent = self.keyPressEvent
    QgsMapCanvas.keyPressEvent = self.keyPressEvent
    QgsMapCanvas.keyPressed = self.keyPressEvent

def keyPressEvent(self, event):
    if type(event) == QtGui.QKeyEvent:
        print("Yes")
    print("Key pressed")
    if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Escape:
        pass
    elif event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_J:
        self.on_zoom_to_level()
```

Answer (score 0):

Qt provides a mechanism to intercept event called [eventFilter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters).
The event filter can be any QObject-derived class, providing it defines the method `eventFilter`.

```
class MyEventFilter(QObject):
    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        """ 
        obj : QObject whose event is intercepted 
        event: QEvent received
        
        returns:
            bool: True to intercept the event, False to forward it
        """
        if event.type() == QEvent.KeyRelease:
            if event.key() == Qt.Key_A:
                print("A key pressed")
                return True
        return False

# Create and install the event filter on the QgsMapCanvas
eventFilter = MyEventFilter()
iface.mapCanvas().installEventFilter(eventFilter)

...

# Then to remove it
iface.mapCanvas().removeEventFilter(eventFilter)
```

Note that  if you want to filter mouse events, you need to install the event filter on the canvas' viewport

```
class MyEventFilter(QObject):
    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        """ 
        obj : QObject whose event is intercepted 
        event: QEvent received
        
        returns:
            bool: True to intercept the event, False to forward it
        """
        if isinstance(obj, QgsMapCanvas):
            if event.type() == QEvent.KeyRelease:
                if event.key() == Qt.Key_A:
                    print("A key pressed")
                    return True
        else:
            if event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonRelease:
                print("Mouse Released")
                return False

        return False


eventFilter = MyEventFilter()
iface.mapCanvas().installEventFilter(eventFilter)
iface.mapCanvas().viewport().installEventFilter(eventFilter)
```